# In Oracle, how to list all the tables in *my* schema that *I* created (without having DBA privileges)

Tags: oracle

I'm an Oracle11XE user with privileges to create and drop tables and procedures.  I create a few tables, then while visiting the restroom, MIB zap me with a memory wipe (I foolishly looked into the light).  Returning to sit at my workstation, I realize I need to query the database with my regular user privs, and figure out what that table or tables I created and the DBA has mysteriously gone missing.

Comment: check dictionary view USER_TABLES and ALL_TABLES. Alternatively USER/ALL_OBJECTS for other types of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `USER_TABLES` view to get all the tables currently in your schema:

```
select table_name
  from user_tables
```

If, additionally, you are interested in knowing *when* the tables were created, then you can use the `USER_OBJECTS` view where `OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'`. That view includes the `CREATED` column.

```
select object_name, created
  from user_objects
 where object_type = 'TABLE'
```

Comment: Fantastic! The first `select` with a `where` does the trick.  `select * from user_tables where table_name = 'foo';`  At first I had a problem because I forgot that when I put quotes around something, I'd better pay attention to the case.  SQL is allowing me to be lazy about case sensitivity and then I got too lazy.